# MySQL rounding of Float Data type

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, floating-point

set up a table in mySQL with a column FLOAT(2,2), then tried to insert 10 and it diaplayed 0.99?

Comment: use FLOAT(2,2) NOT NULL

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of the column definition is `FLOAT(<total number of digits>,<number of fraction digits>)`.

Your column has only 2 total and both of them are fraction.

I'm guessing what you want is `FLOAT(4,2)`.

Answer (score 0):

float(m,n) means total digit upto m and after decimal upto n

For example float(5,2) can store digits as 999.99 or -99.99 means 2 digits after decimal and rest 3 digits before decimal.

In your case you have float(2,2) means total 2 digit and both 2 after decimal.